# Most efficient way to check what keywords (10k words) appear in an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, search

I have several arrays of 100 strings which contain comments that I have retrieved using fetch. (Called `comments`) and another array containing 10,000 keywords. (Called `keywords`)

For each comment in the array I want to check which of the keywords it contains. (I need to know all of the keywords it contains but do not need to know how many times it occurs)

What is the fastest way to do this?

I have tried `forEach` loops within each other:

```
keywords.forEach(word => {
    comments.forEach(comment => {
       if(comment.includes(word)) //call a function
    }
})
```

as well as `for` loops within each other:

```
for(i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < comments.length; j++){
         if(comments[j].includes(keywords[i])) //call a function
    }
}
```

For both of these I have tried switching the inner and outer loops.

I have also tried building a regular expression with my keywords and matching against that using `matchAll` and a `for..of` loop.

```
keywords.forEach(word => regex = regex + `(^|\\b)${word}(\\b|$)|`)
comments.forEach(comment => {
    const matches = comment.matchAll(regex)
    for (const match of matches){
       //call a function
    }
})
```

These all worked on my initial test of ~10 keywords but obviously it is going to take a lot longer with 10,000 keywords.  What is the most efficient way of doing this?

This is all quite new to me so there is a chance I am missing something obvious!

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, you're right, basically  nested loop are bad for time performance if you have large inputs (i.e O(N2) see BigO notation).
You can avoid this nested loop and cut the time by converting the keywords into an object. See this answer, I think it will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411784/7015414

Comment: Thank you. Converting to object and using an index is a good idea. I will try this one too and see how it compares.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `Set`. I've made a `Set` out of the `keywords` array, now for every word in the `comments` array, I can lookup in the `Set` if it contains that word or not.

```js
const keywords = ["java", "golang", "python", "ruby"];

const comments = ["I love java", "Golang is by google", "Python bit me hard"];

const hash = new Set(keywords.map((k) => k.toLowerCase()));

const test = (w) => console.log(w);

comments.forEach((c) =>
  c.split(" ").forEach((w) => hash.has(w.toLowerCase()) && test(w))
);
```

Comment: @nathanael Can you please test this and let me know if this is performant enough.

Comment: I have just tried this and it seemed to work well. I'll do some more testing to compare speeds but this looks good. Thank you!

Comment: @nathanael Glad that it helped, you may consider accepting it as an answer for the others to benefit.